# PHP SQL - Advanced delete query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns: `id`, `date` and `name`. What I am looking for is to delete the records that have a duplicate name. The rule should be to keep the record that has the oldest date. For instance in the example below, there is 3 records with the name Paul. So I would like to keep the one that has the oldest date `(id=1)` and remove all the others `(id = 4 and 6)`. I know how to make insert, update, etc queries, but here I do not see how to make the trick work.

```
id, date, name

1, 2012-03-10, Paul
2, 2012-03-10, James
4, 2012-03-12, Paul
5, 2012-03-11, Ricardo
6, 2012-03-13, Paul
```

`mysql_query(?);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best suggestion I can give you is **create a unique index** on `name` and avoid all the trouble.

Follow the steps as `Peter Kiss` said from 2 to 3. Then do this

```
ALTER Table tablename ADD UNIQUE INDEX name (name)
```

Then Follow 4 `Insert everything from the temporary table to the original`.

All the new duplicate rows, will be omitted

Comment: Hello Starx. Just had time to test what you are proposing this morning. I like it because it is simple. The thing is is, when runing an insert query, is there a way to know if the record has not been inserted because the value already existed in the table. I tried mysql_error, but nothing is retrieved in that case...

Comment: @Marc, You can check mysql's [insert on duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. Select all the records what you want to keep
2. Insert them to a temporary table
3. Delete everything from the original table
4. Insert everything from the temporary table to the original

Comment: Hello Peter? Thanks for the reply. What do you think about the solution proposed by pritaeas?

Comment: The approach is good, the solution is not. First, you have to create a query with the ORDER BY clause and then can you have a SELECT with GROUP BY statement: SELECT `id` FROM (SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `table` ORDER BY `date`) GROUP BY `name`. In this case the GROUp BY will keep the oldest rows from the result set.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT tablename.id FROM (
        SELECT MIN(date) as dateCol, name FROM tablename GROUP BY name /*select the minimum date and name, for each name*/
    ) as MyInnerQuery 
    INNER JOIN tablename on MyInnerQuery.dateCol = tablename.date 
        and MyInnerQuery.name = tablename.name /*select the id joined on the minimum date and the name*/
) /*Delete everything which isn't in the list of ids which are the minimum date fore each name*/
```

Comment: Hello Matt. Thanks. I will need a little time to test that out... I'll come back

Comment: Hello Matt. Had time to test this out this morning and it is unfortunately not working. Nevertheless I get the logic of your solution, but do not get why it is not working....

Answer (score 1):

Like Matt, but without the join:

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `id` NOT IN (
    SELECT `id` FROM (
        SELECT `id` FROM `table` GROUP BY `name` ORDER BY `date`
    ) as A 
)
```

Without the first SELECT you will get "You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: Hello pritaeas. Thank for trying to help me out. What does the 'as A' mean?

Comment: @Marc A is a name for the inner query

Comment: @pritaeas Surely that will return all ids (And thus delete none), you need a top 1 or similar don't you?

Comment: The group/order by selects the oldest one per name. It worked with the test data he provided, records 1, 2 and 4 remained.

Comment: my mysql is totally overloaded at the moment. I will not be abble to test this out for a moment. When I'll be abble to and will test that straight ahead and revert to this post. Thanks to everyone for the moment...

Comment: @pritaeas Are you sure this would work with a larger dataset - my understanding is that the order by will get applied after teh group by - meaning there's no guarantee you'll be retrieving the correct list of IDs not to delete

Comment: No, am not sure, and did not test yet. I see your point, thanks.

Comment: Hello there. I tested the solution proposed by pritaeas and it works on a very small dataset. I am now confused whether to use it or not as  matt and priteas seem to think that it might be unstable with larger datasets...

Comment: Wise. I'd go with Matt's solution at this point. I've not yet had time to research more, but I'm fairly sure he's right.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE t
FROM tableX AS t
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT name
           , MIN(date) AS first_date
      FROM tableX
      GROUP BY name
    ) AS grp
    ON  grp.name = t.name
    AND grp.first_date = t.date
WHERE
    grp.name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM thetable tt
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM thetable tx
    WHERE tx.thename = tt.thename
    AND tx.thedate > tt. thedate
    );
```

(note that "date" is a reserver word (type) in SQL, "and" name is a reserved word in some SQL implementations)